# Why don't two 50% opacity layers of the same color make the solid color in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, gradient

I am trying to create a gradient that when flipped and overlayed on itself will show a solid color.

I thought I would make it with a regular solid-to-transparent gradient on Photoshop, and save it as PNG, but when superimposed on one another, it still shows some transparency.

I tried to do it inside Photoshop and the same experiment with regular layers that had 50% opacity does not show the solid color (i.e. it does not "kill" the transparency).

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post an image to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: for me using 61.8% made it so both end up being ~100%, `.618 + .618*.618 = 0.99994254`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opacity is a multiplier. Assume:

- Layer 1 opacity = 50%
- Layer 2 opacity = 50%
- Layer 3 opacity = 50%

Net opacity = Layer1 + (Layer2 * Layer1) + (Layer3 * Layer2 * Layer1)

Or, 50% + 25% + 12.5%. You would mathematically never get to 100%.

Comment: The related function is `f(x) = 2^-x`. As `x` approaches infinity, `y` approaches `0`. So, in our case, the transparency would never cancel out (be zero).

Answer (score 4):

The way I look at it, each layer lets 50% of the light through... you don't get 100% with it.

It's like the weatherman saying there's a 50% chance of rain on Saturday and on Sunday, and concluding that it must rain sometime during the weekend. Obviously it doesn't mean that. :-)

Comment: That sounds right.  The first layer lets through 50% of the light.  The second layer lets through 50% of remaining light.  Result: 25% of the light gets through.  (I'm not a Photoshop user, but if its layers emulate real-world physics, that's how I'd expect them to behave.)

Comment: Hey thanks, I think that's it. "50% of 50% is not 0". 

So, any ideas how I might be able to create that gradient that flipped makes the solid color?

Comment: @Ozkar: I think I figured it out: Check out the *Subtract* "Mode" above the *Layers* tab. Make the upper layer subtract from the lower layer (which is normal), and you should be able to get something working after playing around with it.

Comment: Mmmh... I'm on CS3, I can't find 'Subtract', I tried 'Difference' and 'Exclusion' and none seem to get me near there. :S (I want a pixel-perfect solution, because if I try to make it aprox, by looking at it I will mess it up hehe.

Comment: Your weather example is misguided. If the two days were independent, the probability of rain for the weekend would be `25%`.

Comment: @iglvzx: Wait, what? I think you misunderstood. I meant that he can't conclude it must rain *sometime* during the weekend, not the *entire* weekend. I'll clarify it.